# Django app not compatible with buildpack https://.../python.tgz

Tags: python, django, heroku

I want to deploy my Django application to Heroku but I'm having trouble when I try to push. When I run `git push heroku master` it says:

```
Counting objects: 99, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (97/97), done.
Writing objects: 100% (99/99), 2.51 MiB | 98.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 99 (delta 22), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to mammadovs.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/mammadovs.git
```

I manually set my buildpack by running `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`.

Comment: (a) If you only need one buildpack there's usually no need to `heroku buildpacks:set` _anything_. Heroku will infer the correct buildpack based on the files in your source code. (b) The files that you need for Python are either `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, and they must be in the root directory of your project. Do you have those files in that location?

Comment: @Chris not, there are not such files in my root directory, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared any dependencies.

Decide if you want to use `Pipenv` or `pip` and add the appropriate dependency files to your repository. If you're new to this the simplest solution is likely to add a `requirements.txt` file containing

```
Django==2.2.3
```

to the root directory in your project. If you have other dependencies, add them too. Then commit the file and redeploy.

Defining your dependencies is important and you should always do it as a best practice. But it's *required* on Heroku. How else would Heroku know that it should install Django and whatever other libraries you use?

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies